# Printing a 2D std::string array

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize a tic-tac-toe board in c++ but the output always gives me hexa values. Is there a way to transform them into actual string values ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string tab[5][5] = { "1","|","2","|","3",
                         "-","+","-","+","-",
                         "4","|","5","|","6",
                         "-","+","-","+","-",
                         "7","|","8","|","9" };

    for(int i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
    {
        cout << tab[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself what is the type of `tab[i]`.  Now ask yourself how do I print that type.

Comment: Change `string tab[5][5]` to `string tab[25]` and print the `std::endl` after each 5th value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sending the value of `tab[i]` to `cout`, so you're getting the memory address.

You probably want to get the items nested deeper, like `tab[i][j]`.

Answer (score 4):

`tab[i]` is a `std::string[]` - that is, an array of `std::string` rather than a `std::string` itself.

Use ranged-`for` instead for your output. As well as the Standard Library containers, it works with built-in arrays:

```
for (const auto &row : tab) {
  for (const auto &c : row) {
    cout << c;
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: the range for works with built in arrays because arrays are not pointers.  The array name holds on to its size information and `std::begin` and `std::end` are overloaded to work with arrays and get the right values.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the answers, that propose a loop at the place of output are correct. If you happen to have to output your tic tac toe field at many different places in your application, you might prefer to encapsulate that. One possible solution is to have a tic tac toe class:

```
struct TicTacToe : public std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> {
    TicTacToe() :
        // not sure, if the initialization will work like that
        std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3>{{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}
    {};
};
```

and then define an output operator for it:

```
auto operator << (std::ostream& out, const TicTacToe& field)
    -> std::ostream& {
  return
      out << std::accumulate(std::begin(field),
                             std::end(field),
                             std::string{},
                             [](const std::string& a,
                                const std::array<int, 3> b)
                                 -> std::string {
                               return 
                                   std::accumulate(std::begin(b),
                                                   std::end(b),
                                                   std::string{},
                                                   [](const std::string& a, int b)
                                                       -> std::string {
                                                     return std::string{b < 0 ?
                                                                          "O" :
                                                                          (b > 0 ? "X" : " ")} +
                                                            (a.empty() ? "" : "|")
                                                   }) +
                                   (a.empty() ? "" : "\n-+-+-\n");
                             });

}
```

Please note, that I have not tested this code. It is meant to give you an idea, not a source for copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

That's more like it thanks a lot !

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string tab[5][5] = { "1","|","2","|","3",
                         "-","+","-","+","-",
                         "4","|","5","|","6",
                         "-","+","-","+","-",
                         "7","|","8","|","9" };

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            cout << tab[i][j];

            if (j == 4)
            cout << endl;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Save yourself an `if`. Remove the `if` and move the `cout << endl;` out of the inner `for` loop. `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            cout << tab[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }`The inner `for` will finish printing the line and exit, the outer loop will print the end of line and loop back to the next line.  Also consider replacing the `endl` with `'\n'` because `endl` does more than just end the line and that more is a very expensive operation.

Comment: It's better to use range-based `for` loop instead of `for(int i = 0;...`. You don't need to replace the `5`s if the size changes; you can get rid of the `[i]`...